# apple watch CMDeviceMotion is not giving me good readings

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, core-motion

Currently, I am just recording a bunch of motion data and saving it to a file. However, when I plot the data, I am having a hard time believing I am getting the right readings. Here is my watch code:

```
- (IBAction)startStopRecording {
    if (!recording){
        NSLog(@"starting to record");
        recording = YES;
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.startRecording setTitle:@"Stop Recording"];
        if (self.motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable) {
            [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
                [data addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f", motion.attitude.pitch, motion.attitude.roll, motion.attitude.yaw, motion.userAcceleration.x, motion.userAcceleration.y, motion.userAcceleration.z, motion.rotationRate.x, motion.rotationRate.y, motion.rotationRate.z]];
                NSLog(@".");
            }];
        }
    }else{
        recording = NO;
        NSLog(@"stopping recording");
        [self.motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
        [self.startRecording setTitle:@"Start Recording"];
        [InterfaceController openParentApplication:@{ @"data": data } reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Data has been saved.");
            NSLog(@"replyInfo %@", replyInfo);
        }];
    }
}
```

The parent application just writes all the data to a file. I recorded the watch rotating back and forth on all three axes (pitch, then roll, then yaw):

[image]

And then when I plotted the data, this is what I got:

[image: pitch plot]
[image: roll plot]
[image: yaw plot]

The yaw is so noisy that you can't see a signal at all in there. I also have a similar problem when plotting the acceleration after jerking the watch in three different directions. I can see spikes of acceleration, but they don't seem to be direction dependent. Any ideas on how to improve this? Am I missing something? Could I just have a bad sensor in my watch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because I wasn't actually pulling data from the watch. It was pulling data from the phone. In order to pull data (currently only acc data is available from the watch) you need to have watchOS2 (currently in beta). Otherwise the watch will just get handed data from the phone.

Comment: Same with the published WtachOS 2, no difference. Even it's available in the WatchOS 2, the real device doesn't deliver any data about the AppleWatch. Really frustrating...

Comment: You have to set things up a little differently for watchOS2 than watchOS1 in order to pull the data. Unfortunately, I don't remember what tutorial I followed to do it, but I do remember I had to set up an app group and pretty much have a separate app for the phone and for the watch. And you can only pull the accelerometer data. Gyro data isn't available yet.

Comment: it's nothing with data transfer/share as app group or WatchOS 1 or 2. isDeviceMotionAvailable is always false on AppleWatch even with the latest WatchOS 2.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I don't know if I ever successfully pulled gyro data from the phone. Once I realised I couldn't get accelerometer the project wasn't feasible, so I probably didn't even try to pull gyro.